# PHP: Problem in a SQL statement when using a String Parameter

Tags: php, mysql

```
$befal = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = $_GET[username]");
$rad = mysql_fetch_assoc($befal);
```

Equals

```
Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in C:\profile.php on line 4
```

I have a user called Admin in the field username and it still dont work. profile.php?user=Admin...

This works if I use the ID though:

```
$befal = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = $_GET[id]");
$rad = mysql_fetch_assoc($befal);
```

What can be the problem?

Thanks

Comment: Don’t forget to sanatize the data before using it in a database query.

Comment: you should check the return value for mysql_query() and if it fails look at mysql_error(). That should give you some idea of why a query is failing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
$befal = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$_GET[username]'");
```

You have to encapsulate a string parameter in apostrophes.

**[UPDATE]**

Just like [cletus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572731/php-problem-in-a-sql-statement-when-using-a-string-parameter/572744#572744) and [Olaf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572731/php-problem-in-a-sql-statement-when-using-a-string-parameter/572742#572742) pointed out, with the above sql statement you are **very prone to SQL Injection**.  Check out their posted answers to see what I mean.

Comment: @Dreas Grech: I suggest you put the big fat warning above your code. I was already on the down-voting button with the mouse for suggesting working but intrinsically broken code.

Answer (score 6):

Errr... that's a recipe for getting hacked.  I would like to introduce you to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) as characterized by this [very funny yet poignant cartoon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84556/whats-your-favorite-programmer-cartoon/84629#84629).

Try this instead.

```
$username = mysql_escape_string($_GET['username']);
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username'");
```

Comment: +1 though I probably would have put forward mysqli. And the cartoon is great. *lol*

Comment: I've given up on mysqli.  Too unstable and noone is fixing the bugs.

Comment: Hm. Admittedly, I don't do enough PHP to have come across any bugs in mysqli. I believe it would work for this trivial scenario, though. ;-) Maybe it's PDO, then. In any case I'm all in favor of prepared/parametrized statements.

Answer (score 0):

Now that you've got your answer, try entering

```
Something' OR '1' = '1
```

as username - you've managed to produce a nice [SQL-injectable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sql_injection) application.

Comment: should i use mysql_real_escape_string on it first to fix this?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know php-functions in depth - cletus suggests mysql_escape_string. See also here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973/what-is-the-best-way-to-avoid-sql-injection-attacks