# Replace spaces in URL with underline

Tags: php, sql

How can I replace spaces in URL with a underline(_)?

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$_GET[user]'");
```

But if a user has a space in her/his username I wanna replace the space with an underline.
So the URL for profile.php?user=John Johnson would be profile.php?user=John_Johnson.

How can I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

As mentioned elsewhere, str_replace will do what you are specifically looking for, but...

I'd be more worried about `profile.php?user=John' DROP DATABASE--`

Don't build queries like this.  EVER.  See [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) for one reason why.  Take a look at [this article](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/4.1/prepared-statements.html) for the right way to do it.

Oh, and [a comic](http://xkcd.com/327/) to use as a memory aid to reinforce that you should NEVER do this.

EDIT: In response to your response (you're better off editing your original question so that it's obvious that you are clarifying your question).  If you have the user 'John Johnson' stored in the database, but you want to access him with the URL `profile.php?user=John_Johnson`, you need to reverse the replacement you are doing:

```
 $user  = str_replace('_', ' ', $_GET['user']);
 $user  = mysql_escape_string($user);
 $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$user'");

 // finns inte användaren så skriver vi ut ett felmeddelande
 if (!mysql_num_rows($query)) exit('<p>The user you are looking for appears to be          missing.</p>');
```

This will take `profile.php?user=John_Johnson` and produce the sql query: `SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = 'John Johnson'`

The sample code you replied with would take `profile.php?user=John Johnson` and produce the sql query: `SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = 'John_Johnson'` which I suspect is the opposite of what you want.

But again, I'd strongly recommend looking into prepared statements.  `mysql_escape_string` is really a stop-gap measure.  All it takes is forgetting to use it once and you've opened up your site to hacking.

Comment: Sound advice, but this is not an answer to the question. Things like this should be posted in comments instead.

Answer (score 3):

Don't create SQL strings from unchecked user input.

At least use `mysql_escape_string()` [to avoid being hacked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84556/whats-your-favorite-programmer-cartoon/84629#84629) on fist sight:

```
$user  = str_replace(' ', '_', $_GET[user]);
$user  = mysql_escape_string($user);
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$user'");
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you do not need regular expressions to do this replacement, you should avoid them since they have significant overhead.

Furthermore, since you're only after characters and not strings, you should go for the function written for character-to-character mapping:  strtr()

```
$result = strtr($original, " ", "_");
```

Answer (score 2):

[str_replace](https://www.php.net/str_replace)?

Answer (score 2):

Use [str_replace()](http://se.php.net/str_replace) like this:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = 'str_replace(' ', '_',$_GET[user])'");
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just replace it in the actual variable using str_replace or strtr. Strtr is usually shown to be faster.

```
$newUsername = strtr($_GET['user'], ' ', '_');
```

Should do it, and your new query:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$newUsername'");
```

Answer (score 1):

Biff,

Try this:

```
$user = urldecode($_GET['user']);
```

`$user` now contains 'John Smith' instead of 'John%20Smith', which I assume is why the query was failing.

```
$user = mysql_escape_string($user);
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = $user");
```

Your problem seems to be with URL Encoded characters preventing a match. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The [str_replace](http://sk.php.net/str_replace) function is what you are looking for. (There are some other alternatives but str_replace is enough for this case)

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '" . str_replace(' ', '_', $_GET[user] . "'");
```

**WARNING:** You should seriously read something about SQL injection. Here is some introduction:

http://sk.php.net/security.database.sql-injection

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at [preg_replace()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) and replace all " " with "_" like so:

```
$result = preg_replace("\s", "_", $_GET['user']);
```

But you should not be putting user input directly into a query like that. Look into PHP input sensitization.

**EDIT:** Sorry forgot that regex requires \s to mean a space.

Answer (score 0):

weird none of your codes seem to work...
i have a user called John Johnson in the database. It works with the ones without space.

The code:

```
     $user  = str_replace(' ', '_', $_GET['user']);
     $user  = mysql_escape_string($user);
     $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$user'");

     // finns inte användaren så skriver vi ut ett felmeddelande
     if (!mysql_num_rows($query)) exit('<p>The user you are looking for appears to be          missing.</p>');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$path = "your website and the path here"; // like http://stackoverflow.com/index.php?id=1
$page = $_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"];
if(stristr($page, ' ')) {
    $page = str_replace(" ","_" , $page);
    $page = str_replace("%20%","_" , $page);
    $page = str_replace("%20","_" , $page);
    $page = str_replace("q=","" , $page);
    echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0; url=$path/$page\" />";
    die();
}
```

If you got the page like website.com/index.phphdsdhdh
you should remove this line

```
$page = str_replace("q=","" , $page);
```

if you want to stop sql injection you can use

```
addslashes();
```

or use this function

```
$page = strtolower($_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]); if(stristr($page, 'union' or stristr($page, 'and' or stristr($page, 'or' or stristr($page, 'select'){ die("sql injection attack");}
```

put it in config

Comment: welcome to SO! When posting code, make sure to format it by selecting the text and hitting the curly braces button `{}`