# Eric Schmidt's aspects of e-mail not in Twitter

Tags: email

In [Google CEO Eric Schmidt's comments about twitter](http://www.businessinsider.com/google-ceo-twitter-a-poor-mans-email-system-2009-3) he highlights some aspects of the e-mail system that twitter lacks.

The aspects of e-mail he mentions are:

- storage
- revocation
- identity

Could anyone explain these aspects of the traditional e-mail system?  I'm interested in creating a twitter-like system and would like to better understand existing communication protocols and their abilities/characteristics.

Comment: How is this related to the act of programming?

Comment: How is this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/84556/whats-your-favorite-programmer-cartoon ? If I could vote to close that, I would. Or, I'd lighten up. One of the two :)

Comment: previous NPR questions do not justify more.

Comment: @Andy: Appealing to common practice is a logical fallacy and does not make this question anymore suitable for this site.

Comment: If I were designing an e-mail system, it would be very useful to understand the terminology regarding the capabilities of the system.

Comment: @Daniel, consider editing your question to point out the programming-ness of it.

Comment: @Daniel, nicely done. Voted to reopen.

Comment: @Daniel. Now THAT's a programming question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since after 6 hrs. no one has answered this I'll give it a try.

- storage

Well you can't store your tweets the same way you can store your e-mail, do you?

- revocation

Mmhh, perhaps because in an e-mail you can take back some comment or discuss back and forward about some topic keeping the thread in one place.

- identity

  The email identifies you as a user in a domain ( user@domain ) hence creates an on line identity. Twitter does not ( at least yet )

Twitter didn't include these kind of features because its nature was well, not being an e-mail susbtitute.

web-forums ( like this ) also evolved from the e-mail system, where all the questions/answers use the e-mail as communication channel.

Comment: I don't know about the identity one. rexm@twitter is as globally unique as rex@rexmorgan.net. Just one is more commonly accepted.

Comment: For storage, on twitter one can still see the history of their tweets, no?  Interesting take on revocation.  And I would agree with Rex's idea of on-line identity.

Comment: @Daniel: Not like in e-mail ( at least not like gmail :P ) @Both: On the identity, I don't know my self either. I move from Yahoo to gmail once, so I was not so tied to the e-mail after all. But definitely my work e-mail and my friends e-mail are used as my web identity. Only time will tell