# C# for loop help

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does “for(;;)” do in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982452/what-does-for-do-in-c)

what does

```
for (; ; )
{
  // do something
}
```

mean in c#?

Isn't there supposed to be (*initializer*, *condition*, *iterator*) ?

I saw an example in a book that uses nothing inside the contents of the for loop.

Comment: It's pronounced as "for-ever".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That would create an unconditional (infinite) loop which has no initializer or iterator.

same as

```
while(true)
{
...
}
```

You'll have to use `break;` to get out of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

At warning level 4 compilers complain about conditional expressions that always evaluate to true, such as while(1) or while(true).

So a common way to suppress the compiler warnings for that is to use for (;;) blocks.

(Im not saying its a good practice), but if you have to create code that compiles at warning level 4 its a habit to use for (;;) instead of while (true).

Comment: The C# compiler does not whine on `while (true)`, nor does any C/C++ compiler that I can remember.

Comment: with the standard warning level 3 you are right, but with warning level 4 it will.

Answer (score 0):

Its just a loop that will run continuously.

Answer (score 0):

Like the other answers say, it's a loop that runs continuously until you break it with `break;`

It's usefull if you want to break on a condition that you create within the loop but you have no access to yet at the definition of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's how an infinite loop is defined using a for statement.

You could read that as:

```
for (bool run = true; run == true; run &= true)
{
    // do something
}
```

See what the [C# Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch45axte.aspx) has to say about that