# hashCode implementation for singleton class

Tags: java

what will be the implementation for

```
public int hashCode()
{
}
```

method in singleton class? Please do provide me the implementation

Comment: How about "throw new UnsupportedOperationException()" :)

Answer (score 11):

Since there's only one object, you don't have to worry about making other, equal, objects have the same hashCode.  So you can just use [System.identityHashCode](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#identityHashCode%28java.lang.Object%29) (i.e. the default).

Answer (score 6):

If it's a singleton, you don't need to provide an implementation, as it will be the same object instance wherever it's used. The default (System.identityHashCode(obj)) will be sufficient, or even just a constant number (eg 5)

Comment: I think 4 is the correct random number to return

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/84556/whats-your-favorite-programmer-cartoon/84747#84747

Comment: BTW, here we don't need a random number. It would be an overkill. :)

Comment: `@Override public int hashCode() { return "huh?".length(); }`

Answer (score 4):

```
public int hashCode() {
    return 42; // The Answer to the Ultimate Question of Life, The Universe and Everything
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use the singleton ENUM pattern instead (Effective Java #??), you'll get hashCode and equals for free.

Answer (score 1):

```
Objects of singleton class always return same hashcode. Please find below code snippet,

#Singleton class
public class StaticBlockSingleton {
    //Static instance
    private static StaticBlockSingleton instance;

    public int i;

    //Private constructor so that class can't be instantiated 
    private StaticBlockSingleton(){}

    //static block initialization for exception handling
    static {
        try{
            instance = new StaticBlockSingleton();
        }catch(Exception e){
            throw new RuntimeException("Exception occured in creating singleton instance");
        }
    }

    public static StaticBlockSingleton getInstance(){
        return instance;
    }

    public void printI(){
        System.out.println("------ " + i);
    }
}


#Singletone Client
public static void main(String[] arg) {
        System.out.println("From Main");
        StaticBlockSingleton s1  = StaticBlockSingleton.getInstance();
        s1.i = 100;
        System.out.println("S1 hashcode --- " + s1.hashCode());
        StaticBlockSingleton s2  = StaticBlockSingleton.getInstance();
        s2.i = 200;
        System.out.println("S2 hashcode --- " + s2.hashCode());
        s1.printI();
        s2.printI();
    }


#Output
From Main
S1 hashcode --- 1475686616
S2 hashcode --- 1475686616
------ 200
------ 200
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to repeat other answers here. So yes, if you are using a Singleton then [Matthew's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108653/hashcode-implementation-for-singleton-class/1108662#1108662) is what you want. Make sure you are not confusing [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern#Example_implementations) with just an [immutable object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object). If you have an immutable object, then you will have to implement a hashCode() method.

Remember there is only ever at most one instance of a singleton. Therefore, the default hashCode is sufficient.

```
public class ImmutableNotSingleton {
    private final int x;
    public ImmutableNotSingleton(int x) { this.x = x; }

    // Must implement hashCode() as you can have x = 4 for one object,
    // and x = 2 of another
    @Override public int hashCode() { return x; }
}
```

If you were using an immutable, don't forget to override equals() if when you override hashCode().