# What is the best way to generate random numbers in C++?

Tags: c++, random, numbers

What is the best way to generate random numbers?

Comment: Why is `rand` not good to use?

Comment: because you should divide and plus and ... to make the number between two numbers! there must be beter functions

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I came here because rand is generating the same results every time...

Comment: @TomášZato So show the code that had the problem and ask how to fix it.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz "Why is `rand` not good to use?" - See [rand() Considered Harmful](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/events/goingnative-2013/rand-considered-harmful).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## **If and only if:**

- #### you are not looking for "perfect uniformity" or
- #### you have no C++11 support and not even TR1 (thus you don't have another choice)

**then** you might consider using the following C-style solution, which (for the sake of the reputation of this community ~ see [rand() Considered Harmful](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful)) is written in strike-through font:

Here's the simple C-style function that generates random number from the interval from `min` to `max`, inclusive. Those numbers seem to be very close to being uniformly distributed.

```
int irand(int min, int max) {
    return ((double)rand() / ((double)RAND_MAX + 1.0)) * (max - min + 1) + min;
}
```

and don't forget to call `srand` before you use it:

```
int occurrences[8] = {0};

srand(time(0));
for (int i = 0; i < 100000; ++i)
    ++occurrences[irand(1,7)];

for (int i = 1; i <= 7; ++i)
    printf("%d ", occurrences[i]);
```

output: `14253 14481 14210 14029 14289 14503 14235`

Also have a look at:
[Generate a random number within range?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2999075/1168156)
[Generate random numbers uniformly over an entire range](https://stackoverflow.com/q/288739/1168156)
and find some time and watch at least first 11 minutes of aforementioned [video](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful)

## Otherwise:

use [`<random>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) just like it was pointed out by [Kerrek SB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/596781/kerrek-sb) already.

Comment: Your `irand` implementation does *not* produce uniformly distributed random numbers: some values are more likely than others as explained in the [rand() considered harmful](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful) talk. Your very example is described at the 7:30 mark.

Comment: @syam: I've seen a link to this speech few times already, but haven't paid attention to it. Finally I watched it and I've edited my answer appropriately :)

Comment: To be fair, the speaker considers your implementation only "subtly" non-uniform, as opposed to other "hilariously" non-uniform solutions. I for one made much worse errors with `rand()`... ;)

Comment: @syam: But in case `<random>` is available, why not go for it? It's cleaner and better solution. It can be wrapped into a standalone helper function like my `irand` as well.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I wasn't advocating the use of your implementation over `<random>`, just pointing out that there are much worse mistakes to make. Of course `<random>` should be preferred if it is available, however if you *must* make do with `rand()` then your solution is probably (one of?) the best we can get.

Comment: `rand()` is great for my unit tests. But on Unix systems you can at least load bytes from `/dev/random` or `/dev/urandom`. Also the OpenSSL library offers RAND (try `man RAND` and `man RAND_bytes`).

Answer (score 33):

You should use `<random>`:

```
#include <random>

typedef std::mt19937 rng_type;
std::uniform_int_distribution<rng_type::result_type> udist(0, 7);

rng_type rng;

int main()
{
  // seed rng first:
  rng_type::result_type const seedval = get_seed(); // get this from somewhere
  rng.seed(seedval);

  rng_type::result_type random_number = udist(rng);

  return random_number;
}
```

Pre C++11 you could find this either in TR1 (`<tr1/random>`, `std::tr1::mt19937` etc.), or in Boost.random, with essentially the same interface (though there are minor differences).

Comment: I don't think there needs to be a correlation between the distribution's return type and the engine's. I usually like to bind the distribution and the engine together unless I have a special reason for needing them separate. Also engines can take the seed in a constructor, so you can put it all in a single line: `auto rand = bind(uniform_int_distribution<>(0,7),mt19937(get_seed()));`

Comment: @bames53: You're right, the integral types of the distribution and of the engine may well be different. Personally, I don't like gratuitous `bind`s very much, but sure, if you want a more compact form, go ahead.

Comment: But how can I get sufficiently random seed?

Comment: @TomášZato: You can use `std::random_device`. The quality of the result depends on your implementation, but it's a start.

Answer (score 6):

[Boost.Random](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_random.html) is an excellent library for producing pseudorandom numbers (or truly random, if the platform supports it).

Comment: I checked their docs just to make sure they are not claiming to produce truly random numbers, and they are not. So why are you including that in your answer?

Comment: @KevinCrowell [Non-deterministic Uniform Random Number Generator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost_random/reference.html#boost_random.reference.concepts.non_deterministic_uniform_random_number_generator)

Comment: It includes `random_device` (as does the now-standard <random> header) to provide access to a non-deterministic uniform random number generator on platforms that have such a device. (E.g. The OS collects random data from doing things like observing network traffic and provides access to that data via /dev/random)

Answer (score 3):

If you're talking standard C++ library pre C++11, rand and srand are your random number generators. There are ways to get more accuracy out of these functions than using modulus with integer arithmetic. You could use doubles, for example, if high speed isn't a concern and round the results to int.

As for custom libraries, if you really want good random distribution and speed, google Mersenne Twister. There are also options in boost.

With C++11 you have `<random>`. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random

Answer (score 2):

My 'random' library provide a high convenient wrapper around C++11 random classes. You can do almost all things with a simple 'get' method.

Examples:

1. Random number in a range

> `auto val = Random::get(-10, 10); // Integer`
>   `auto val = Random::get(10.f, -10.f); // Float point`

2. Random boolean

> `auto val = Random::get<bool>( ) // 0.5% to generate true`
>
> `auto val = Random::get<bool>( 0.7 ) // 0.7% to generate true`

3. Random value from a std::initilizer_list

> ```
> auto val = Random::get( { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 } ); // val = 1 or 3 or...
> ```

4. Random iterator from iterator range or all container

> `auto it = Random::get( vec.begin(), vec.end() ); // it = random iterator`
>
> `auto it = Random::get( vec ); // return random iterator`

And even more things ! Check out the github page:

https://github.com/effolkronium/random

Comment: Quite complete library you have there! I like the fact that one can load/save the current state since that way you do not need to reseed each time which makes it safer, I think.