# C++ generating random numbers-1

Tags: c++, random, netbeans-7, srand

```
int main() 
{ 
  srand((unsigned)time(0)); 
  int random_integer; 
  int lowest=0, highest=10; 
  int range=(highest-lowest)+1; 
  for(int index=0; index<20; index++){ 
    random_integer = (rand() % range) + lowest/(RAND_MAX + 1.0);
    cout << random_integer << endl; 
  } 
}
```

I am getting the output from 0 to 10, 11 numbers, but I don't want to get  number 10, just numbers 0 to 9, that means 10 random numbers, what should I do?

Comment: Remove the `+ 1` from the range evaluation.

Comment: change `highest=10` to `highest=9` ? i wouldnt change the code any other way since your variables give the impression that it should give "highest" number of 10... which wont work anymore if you follow Alexander's advice.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generating random integer from a range](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5008804/generating-random-integer-from-a-range)

Comment: @Alexander, it works perfectly, but i wanna know what that +1 means for the code there... could u please explain it. actual problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modulo operation `x % c;` returns the remainder of division of number `x` by `c`. If you do `x % 10` then there are `10` possible return values: `0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9`.

Note that generating random numbers by using `rand()` with `%` produces skewed results and those numbers are not uniformly distributed. 
Here's the simple C-style function that generates random number from the interval from `min` to `max`, inclusive:

```
int irand(int min, int max) {
    return ((double)rand() / ((double)RAND_MAX + 1.0)) * (max - min + 1) + min;
}
```

Note, that numbers generated by this functions are uniformly distributed:

```
int occurences[8] = {0};

srand(time(0));
for (int i = 0; i < 100000; ++i)
    ++occurences[irand(1,7)];

for (int i = 1; i <= 7; ++i)
    cout << occurences[i] << ' ';
```

output: `14253 14481 14210 14029 14289 14503 14235`

Also have a look at:
[Generate a random number within range?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2999075/1168156)
[Generate random numbers uniformly over an entire range](https://stackoverflow.com/q/288739/1168156)
[What is the best way to generate random numbers in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9471604/1168156)

Comment: okay, but what you're expecting to get, is it 8 random numbers or just 7... because my question is all about the count of numbers that i get... i should only get 10 numbers from lowest being 0 and highest being 10...

Comment: @visanio_learner: If you call my function like this: `irand(0,3)`, there are 4 possible return values: `0, 1, 2, 3`. Hope it's clear now ;)

Comment: @visanio_learner: Thank you. But someone dowvoted it and I'd like to know the reason.

Comment: @visanio_learner: I am not asking you. I just hope someone will read my comment and write the reason he downvoted...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8393/discussion-between-visanio-learner-and-liho)

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you need to fully understand, then modify this line

```
random_integer = (rand() % range) + lowest/(RAND_MAX + 1.0);
```

Answer (score 0):

`rand() % 10` normally does the trick for me.. (unless I'm missing something)

Answer (score 0):

```
int main() 
{ 
  srand((unsigned)time(0)); 
  int random_integer; 
  int lowest=0, highest=9; 
  int range=(highest-lowest)+1; 
  for(int index=0; index<20; index++){ 
    random_integer = (rand() % range) + lowest;
    cout << random_integer << endl; 
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this type of questions have been answered n number of times.

have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2215690/1155650)