# rand() and a Mersenne Twister C++ implementation

Tags: c++, random

I need to implement a good RNG and I guess Mersenne Twister could be good for me.
I didn't find anywhere a working C++ implementation, am I a bad google searcher or is it really not simple to find?!
I've tried before `rand()`:

```
srand((unsigned)time(0));
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
     random =  rand();
     cout<<random;
}
```

I don't know why, but the random variable is always the same number.....BUT if I add a `Sleep(1000)`, it works! Like this:

```
srand((unsigned)time(0));
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    random =  rand();
    cout<<random;
    Sleep(1000);
}
```

So I decided to try Mersenne Twister...Could someone find a solution of this (because I need to find a very very big number of random numbers so I can't use `Sleep(1000)`, it would takes eras!) or help me to implement Mersenne Twister or maybe also another good RNG.
Thanks and sorry for my bad English...

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9471604/1168156

Comment: You are a bad googler, as there is a mersene twister engine in the [standard library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/mersenne_twister_engine) and in [boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/html/boost_random/reference.html)

Comment: http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful

Comment: This is good question too: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4195958/1168156

Comment: boost has one, and even c++ comes with a mersenne twister... so the question is, what is not "good" in them?

Comment: I think you really had the srand() call inside the loop too. there would normally be no reason adding Sleep() would affect the result unless srand() was called inside your loop as well.

Answer (score 7):

C++11 includes a mersenne twister with the [`random` standard library header](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random).

Answer (score 1):

[Boost.Random](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_random.html) is an available implementation, if your STL implementation doesn't have it.

You can use `random_device` to get a random seed, and then pass it to the `mt19937` constructor to initialize the random number generator.
Then you can use `uniform_int_distribution` to get a random integer, *uniformly distributed* in the closed range `[a, b]` that you specify in `uniform_int_distribution` constructor.

You may want to consider this sample code (compiled with g++ 4.8.1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost\nondet_random.hpp>
#include <boost\random.hpp>

int main() {        
    // Get a random seed
    boost::random_device rd;
    const auto seed = rd();

    // Marsenne Twister generator
    boost::random::mt19937 mt(seed);

    // Get random integers uniformly distributed in range [0, 99]
    boost::random::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(0, 99);

    // Print 10 random numbers, uniformly distributed in previous range
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        std::cout << dist(mt) << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;    
}
```