# C++ Segmentation fault when running my random ID generation

Tags: c++, string, random, stdstring

I am currently getting a segmentation fault (Segmentation fault: 11), when I call `newUnitID()`.

No idea what I am doing wrong.

This is my header file where the function is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <vector>
#ifndef UnitManager
#define UnitManager
using namespace std;

char randomIDChar(){
    static const char alphanum[] =
        "0123456789"
        "!@#$%^&*"
        "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
        "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    int stringLength = sizeof(alphanum) - 1;
    srand(time(0));
    for(int z=0; z < 21; z++)
    {
        return alphanum[rand() % stringLength];
    }
    return 1;
}

string newUnitID(){
    vector<char> v;
    for(int i=0; i < 50; i++){
        v[i] = randomIDChar();
    }
    string str(v.begin(),v.end());
    return str;
}

#endif
```

Comment: simonc's answer is good, but may I suggest that you learn to work with a tool such as Valgrind or GDB? The basics are quite easy to pick up (and that's all you need, really), and it can save you a lot of time in trying to find bugs like these in your code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

vector's [operator []](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at) access existing elements; it doesn't create new elements.  You start with an empty vector so

```
v[i] = randomIDChar();
```

access beyond the vector's end.  You could change this to

```
v.push_back(randomIDChar());
```

Note that there is also a problem with `randomIDChar`.  You should only seed the random number generator once, probably before calling either of the functions posted.  Any given seed will generate a predictable stream of 'random' numbers; `time(0)` returns a number of seconds so every call you make within 1 second will have the same seed and so will generate the same number when you later call `rand`

Comment: Thank you! Will try now! Thanks for quick response :D

Comment: It worked great! Thank you! Now I just have to figure out what I'm doing wrong with it generating the same character in the whole string ^^

Comment: @N00byEdge Glad it helped.  I've updated my answer to cover why you aren't getting random characters generated.

Comment: Also, the `for` loop and `return 1` in `randomIDChar()` are totally useless since the function returns the very first time the loop is entered. I can't even begin to guess what you want to achieve here.

Comment: The return 1 was there before I built the function, forgot to remove it ;)

Comment: And the for loop was creating the string, changed it, removing the loop maybe I should have done ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
v[i] = randomIDChar();
```

causes an *undefined behavior* since it attempts to write a character behind the bounds of the array (vector's internal buffer, which hasn't been previously allocated).

Also note that you don't need a vector of characters to later construct a string, you can work directly with `std::string` object. And also note that the way you generate the position of character produces quite skewed results, this would yield better results:

```
char randomIDChar(){
    static const char alphanum[] =
        "0123456789"
        "!@#$%^&*"
        "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
        "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    static int len = 0;
    if (len == 0) {
        srand(time(0));
        len = sizeof(alphanum) - 1;
    }
    int pos = ((double)rand() / ((double)RAND_MAX + 1.0)) * len;
    return alphanum[pos];
}

std::string newUnitID(){
    const int LEN = 50;
    std::string str(LEN, ' ');
    for(int i = 0; i < LEN; i++) {
        str[i] = randomIDChar();
    }
    return str;
}
```

Worth to have a look at: [What is the best way to generate random numbers in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9471604/1168156)