# Random Number Generator C++ Beginner

Tags: c++, random

Hi so I'm trying to make a random number generator as part of my calculator. I have been learning C++ for the past few weeks and I'm not sure what the problem is. Codeblocks can detect no errors but it will not function correctly.

```
          int first;
    int last;
    int counter;

    cout << "Enter range of the numbers you want to generate. eg. Between 1 and 20.\n"  << endl;
    cout << "Between..." << endl;
    cin >> first;
    cout << "And..." << endl;
    cin >> last;
    cout << "Enter the amount of numbers you want to generate: " << endl;
    cin >> counter;
    cout << endl;

    srand(time(0));

    for (int first; last < counter; first++)
    {
        cout << 1+(rand()%last) << endl;
    }
```

Comment: What does it do? What do you want it to do? Any errors?

Comment: You should use a [`random_engine`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random)

Comment: `for (int first; last < counter; first++)` <- wow is this wrong. You don't initialize `first`, loop condition does not include `first`, and nothing in the body changes what the loop condition checks...

Comment: @crashmstr: Also, shadowing

Comment: Related: [What is the best way to generate random numbers in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9471604) you should use the c++11 random facilities if you can.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to generate random numbers in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9471604/what-is-the-best-way-to-generate-random-numbers-in-c)

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> for (int first; last < counter; first++)
>   cout << 1+(rand()%last) << endl;
> ```

From the prompt text it sounds like `first` and `last` have nothing to do with the number of values you want to generate, so they should not appear inside the `for(...)`, only in the body.

```
for (int i=0; i<counter; ++i)
  cout << first+(rand()%(last-first+1)) << endl;
```

---

Also, instead of using `rand()` and `srand()` you should use the C++11 `<random>` library.

```
#include <random>

// create and seed a source of random data
std::random_device r;
std::seed_seq seed{r(), r(), r(), r(), r(), r(), r(), r()};
std::mt19937 rng(seed);

// define the distribution you want
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(first, last);

for (int i = 0; i < counter; ++i) {
  std::cout << dist(rng) << '\n';
}
```

I think in general it's easier to use, although the syntax may be a bit mysterious for beginners. The above declares a couple of variables `dist` and `rng`, initializes them, and then uses `dist` like a function to produce the values you want.

Note in particular how much simpler it is to create the distribution `dist` than for you to compute a distribution yourself: `first+(rand()%(last-first+1))`. That calculation may not even produce a uniform distribution: some values may be produced more often than others. So `<random>` is better because it's easier to use and the meaning is clearer and more explicit.

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple issues here.  First, your for loop is wrong.  What you really want is:

```
for (int i = 0; i < counter; ++i)
```

This will generate the requested amount of random numbers.

Secondly, to generate a random number in the range of "first" to "last", inclusive, you need to determine the difference between "last" and "first", get a random number in that range, then translate that value up to be in the range between "first" and "last":

```
cout << first + (rand() % (last - first + 1)) << endl
```

The "+1" is to guarantee that "last" is inclusive with the allowed range.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean `for (int first=0; first < counter; first++)`

Also, taking modulus of a random number output compromises its properties. Instead you should *scale* it: `1.0 * rand() / RAND_MAX * last;`. RAND_MAX is defined by the standard and 1.0 means stops integer division.

Comment: And first is still uninitialized...

Comment: someone edited it. Hope it wasn't my boss.

Comment: lol... no ;-)... And I think I misunderstood the OP's intentions. @bames53 figured it out.