# picking rand() number from 1-6

Tags: c++, random, generator

I have a simple problem here but no clue how to fix this! I am trying to create a number generator but I only want it to pick a random number from 1-6. No zeros! This question was marked a dup but it shouldn't be because this is *C++* NOT *C*:

```
srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(0)));
int dice = rand()%6;
```

Comment: just add 1 to `dice`.

Comment: Near-duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2999075/179910

Comment: Use `rand()/RAND_MAX * (max_n - min_n) + min_n;`

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan - `rand()/RAND_MAX` will be 0 almost all the time; both expressions have type `int`, and the value returned by `rand()` is never greater than the value of `RAND_MAX`. Use `rand()/double(RAND_MAX)`, or your favorite variant.

Comment: @PeteBecker hmm you are correct, Thanks Pete!

Comment: It is kind of silly to close a C++ question as a dup of a C question since many C++ solutions are not valid C solution, at least find a dup w/ the right tags.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`rand() % 6` gives a number in the range `0..5`. Add one to get the range `1..6`.

Answer (score 9):

If C++11 is an option you also have [`std::uniform_int_distribution`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution) which is somewhat simpler and less error prone(*see [rand() Considered Harmful presentation](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful) and [slides](http://sdrv.ms/1e11LXl)*):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

int main()
{
    std::random_device rd;

    std::mt19937 e2(rd());

    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dist(1, 6);

    for( int i = 0 ; i < 10; ++i )
    {
       std::cout << dist(e2) << std::endl ;
    }

    return 0 ;
}
```

This previous thread [Why do people say there is modulo bias when using a random number generator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10984974/why-do-people-say-there-is-modulo-bias-when-using-a-random-number-generator) explains clearly the modulo bias that chris pointed out in his comment.

Comment: And much better than the `rand()` generator combined with modulus bias.

Comment: @chris Added a link explaining modulo bias

Answer (score 4):

Almost got it:

`int dice = rand()%6 + 1;`