# Pattern for action decision

Tags: c, algorithm

I am writing maze generator and at the some point I have to choose random unvisited neighbour of a cell. The first idea was just to enumerate neighbours such as left = 0, top = 1, right = 2, bottom = 3 and use rand() % 4 to generate random number and choose appropriate cell. However, not all cells features 4 neighbours, so that I had to write following code:

```
Cell* getRandomNeighbour(const Maze* const maze, const Cell* const currentCell) {

int randomNumb = rand() % 4;

int timer = 1;

while(timer > 0) {
    if (randomNumb == 0 && currentCell->x < maze->width-1 && maze->map[currentCell->y][currentCell->x+1].isUnvisited) 
        return &maze->map[currentCell->y][currentCell->x+1];
    if (randomNumb == 1 && currentCell->x > 0 && maze->map[currentCell->y][currentCell->x-1].isUnvisited) 
        return &maze->map[currentCell->y][currentCell->x-1];
    if (randomNumb == 2 && currentCell->y < maze->height-1 && maze->map[currentCell->y+1][currentCell->x].isUnvisited) 
        return &maze->map[currentCell->y+1][currentCell->x];
    if (randomNumb == 3 && currentCell->y > 0 && maze->map[currentCell->y-1][currentCell->x].isUnvisited) 
        return &maze->map[currentCell->y-1][currentCell->x];

    timer--;
    randomNumb = rand() % 4;
}


if (currentCell->x < maze->width-1 && maze->map[currentCell->y][currentCell->x+1].isUnvisited) 
    return &maze->map[currentCell->y][currentCell->x+1];
if (currentCell->x > 0 && maze->map[currentCell->y][currentCell->x-1].isUnvisited) 
    return &maze->map[currentCell->y][currentCell->x-1];
if (currentCell->y < maze->height-1 && maze->map[currentCell->y+1][currentCell->x].isUnvisited) 
    return &maze->map[currentCell->y+1][currentCell->x];
if (currentCell->y > 0 && maze->map[currentCell->y-1][currentCell->x].isUnvisited) 
    return &maze->map[currentCell->y-1][currentCell->x];

return NULL;
}
```

So, if after 10 iterations the right decision isn't chosen, it will be picked by brute force. This approach seems to be good for the reason that varying of variable *timer* changes the complexity of maze: the less *timer* is, the more straightforward maze is. Nevertheless, if my only purpose is to generate completely random maze, it takes a lot of execution time and look a little bit ugly. Is there any pattern(in C language) or way of refactoring that could enable me to deal with this situation without long switches and a lot of if-else constructions?

Comment: You ask for an algorithm. A design-pattern is something completely different.

Comment: Why not push the legal neighbors onto a stack (an array with a depth counter) and pick one of those elements at random, using the depth as the modulus.

Comment: @pat Thanks, it sounds like a good solution, I will try it.

Comment: @pat, @ NikitaRock there might be a corner case when you end up in a dead-end. Then the stack of legal neighbours will be empty. Make sure to add a correct handling of such situation.

Answer (score 1):

As [@pat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/671703/pat) and [@Ivan Gritsenko](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42456967/pattern-for-action-decision#comment72058032_42456967) suggested, you can limit your random choice to the valid cells only, like this:

```
Cell* getRandomNeighbour(const Maze* const maze, const Cell* const currentCell)
{
    Cell *neighbours[4] = {NULL};
    int count = 0;

    // first select the valid neighbours
    if (    currentCell->x  <  maze->width - 1 
         && maze->map[currentCell->y][currentCell->x + 1].isUnvisited ) { 
        neighbours[count++] = &maze->map[currentCell->y][currentCell->x + 1];
    }
    if (    currentCell->x  >  0 
         && maze->map[currentCell->y][currentCell->x - 1].isUnvisited ) {
        neighbours[count++] = &maze->map[currentCell->y][currentCell->x - 1];
    }
    if (    currentCell->y  <  maze->height - 1 
         && maze->map[currentCell->y + 1][currentCell->x].isUnvisited ) {
        neighbours[count++] = &maze->map[currentCell->y + 1][currentCell->x];
    }
    if (    currentCell->y  >  0 
         && maze->map[currentCell->y - 1][currentCell->x].isUnvisited ) {
        neighbours[count++] = &maze->map[currentCell->y - 1][currentCell->x];
    }

    // then choose one of them (if any)
    int chosen = 0;
    if ( count > 1 )    
    {
        int divisor = RAND_MAX / count;
        do { 
            chosen = rand() / divisor;
        } while (chosen >= count);
    }
    return neighbours[chosen];
}
```

The rationale behind the random number generation part (as opposed to the more common `rand() % count`) is well explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2999130/4944425).

Answer (score 0):

Factoring repeated code, and a more disciplined way of picking the order of directions to try yields this:

```
// in_maze returns whether x, y is a valid maze coodinate.
int in_maze(const Maze* const maze, int x, int y) {
    return 0 <= x && x < maze->width && 0 <= y && y < maze->height;
}

Cell *get_random_neighbour(const Maze* const maze, const Cell* const c) {
    int dirs[] = {0, 1, 2, 3};
    // Randomly shuffle dirs.
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        int r = i + rand() % (4 - i);
        int t = dirs[i];
        dirs[i] = dirs[r];
        dirs[r] = t;
    }
    // Iterate through the shuffled dirs, returning the first one that's valid.
    for (int trial=0; trial<4; trial++) {
        int dx = (dirs[trial] == 0) - (dirs[trial] == 2);
        int dy = (dirs[trial] == 1) - (dirs[trial] == 3);
        if (in_maze(maze, c->x + dx, c->y + dy)) {
            const Cell * const ret = &maze->map[c->y + dy][c->x + dx];
            if (ret->isUnvisited) return ret;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

(Disclaimer: untested -- it probably has a few minor issues, for example const correctness).