# why does NULL of srand (time (NULL)) give time () a random value?

Tags: c, random, srand

In C language, use srand (time (NULL)); can produce random numbers from 0 to 32767.
My question is, why does NULL of srand (time (NULL)) give time () a random value?

Also, how to generate random numbers over 32767?

Use

```
if (rand ()% 2 == 0) {ans = rand () + (0b1 << 15);}
else {ans = rand ();}
```

Is it suitable?

Comment: `srand (time (NULL)); can produce random numbers from 0 to 32767`.. `srand()` does not produce any value.

Comment: You don't use `srand` to generate random values; you use `rand()`. The `srand` function sets the seed value for the PRNG that feeds `rand()`. It would probably help to read the documentation of both [`srand()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/random/srand), and [`rand()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/random/rand), where the provided examples clearly tell you what `srand(time(NULL));` is actually doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding *"why does NULL of srand (time (NULL)) give time () a random value?"*

Check the [man page of `time()`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/time), it mentions

> *`time()` **returns** the time as the number of seconds since the Epoch, 1970-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 (UTC). If `t` is non-NULL, the return value is also stored in the memory pointed to by `t`.*

In this usage, we need only the return value, and we don't need to store that value additionally in any buffer, so we pass `NULL` as argument. Also, the returned value is **not random**, it's the number of seconds since the Epoch, 1970-01-01. So every invocation updates the value (strictly incremental).

That said, regarding the range of values returned by calling [`rand()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/rand)

> *The `rand()` function returns a pseudo-random integer **in the range `0` to `RAND_MAX` inclusive** (i.e., the mathematical range `[0, RAND_MAX]`).*

Check the value of `RAND_MAX` in your platform.

That said, `rand()` is a poor PRNG, you can check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2999075/2173917) for better ways to get yourself a random number.

Comment: *So every invocation updates the value (strictly incremental).* ... Not really, which means the value is not random at all. Running the program again during the same second will let it use the same pseudo-random sequence. `srand(clock())` is a much less problematic approach, although still poor for sensitive applications.