# Hibernate, MySQL and table named "Repeat" - strange behaviour

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, orm, jpa

I am having a strange problem. But first the orm.xml:

```
<entity class="de.test.businessobjects.Repeat">
    <table name="repeat"/>
    <attributes>
        <id name="id">
            <generated-value strategy="TABLE"/>
        </id>
        <many-to-one name="repeatType" fetch="LAZY">
            <join-column name="id_repeatType"/>
        </many-to-one>
        <many-to-one name="trainingSet" fetch="LAZY">
            <join-column name="id_trainingSet"/>
        </many-to-one>
    </attributes>
</entity>
```

I use Hibernate / JPA. Everything runs fine with HSQL and Derby, so my BO, DAO and unit tests must be ok. When testing with MySQL, I get this error:

> org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException:
>   could not execute query; SQL [select
>   repeat0_.id as id8_,
>   repeat0_.id_repeatType as id2_8_,
>   repeat0_.id_trainingSet as id3_8_ from
>   repeat repeat0_];

However, changing

```
<table name="repeat"/>
```

to

```
<table name="repeatt"/>
```

solves the problem with MySQL.

What is wrong? Is "repeat" a reserved keyword or is this a bug in Hibernate's JPA implementation?

Thank & Cheers
Er

Comment: Completely unrelated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/84556/whats-your-favorite-programmer-cartoon/84629#84629
[No offense intended]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [SQL Reserved Words Checker](http://www.petefreitag.com/tools/sql_reserved_words_checker/) tells me that ["repeat"](http://www.petefreitag.com/tools/sql_reserved_words_checker/?word=repeat) is a reserved SQL keyword with MySQL (and DB2) so you need to escape it.

JPA 1.0 doesn't define a standard way to handle that so you'll have to use Hibernate solution which relies on backticks. From the Hibernate Reference Guide:

> #### [5.4. SQL quoted identifiers](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-quotedidentifiers)
>
> You can force Hibernate to quote an
>   identifier in the generated SQL by
>   enclosing the table or column name in
>   backticks in the mapping document.
>   Hibernate will use the correct
>   quotation style for the SQL Dialect.
>   This is usually double quotes, but the
>   SQL Server uses brackets and MySQL
>   uses backticks.
>
> ```
> <class name="LineItem" table="`Line Item`">
>     <id name="id" column="`Item Id`"/><generator class="assigned"/></id>
>     <property name="itemNumber" column="`Item #`"/>
>     ...
> </class>
> ```

I *assume* this would work in `orm.xml` too.

JPA 2.0 went further and defined a way to specify delimited identifiers:

> #### 2.13 Naming of Database Objects
>
> ...
>
> To specify delimited identifiers, one of the following approaches must be used:
>
> - It is possible to specify that all database identifiers in use for a persistence unit be treated as delimited identifiers by specifying the `<delimited-identifiers/>` element within the `persistence-unit-defaults` element of the object/relational xml mapping file. If the `<delimited-identifiers/>` element is specified, it cannot be overridden.
> - It is possible to specify on a per-name basis that a name for a database object is to be interpreted as a delimited identifier as follows:
>
>   - Using annotations, a name is specified as a delimited identifier by enclosing the name
>       within double quotes, whereby the inner quotes are escaped, e.g., `@Table(name="\"customer\"")`.
>   - When using XML, a name is specified as a delimited identifier by use of double
>       quotes, e.g., `<table name="&quot;customer&quot;"/>`

If you are using JPA 2.0, I'd recommend to use the portable solution.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, repeat is a reserved word in MySQL

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html