# SQL Error: 1064 Hibernate

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate

This is my Character class:

```
package webgame.model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "character")
public class Character {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "nivel")
    private int nivel;

    @Column(name = "experiencia")
    private int experiencia;

    @Column(name = "fuerza")
    private float fuerza;

    @Column(name = "inteligencia")
    private float inteligencia;

    @Column(name = "aguante")
    private float aguante;

    @Column(name = "agilidad")
    private float agilidad;

    @Column(name = "suerte")
    private float suerte;

    @Column(name = "dinero")
    private float dinero;

    public Character() {
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getNivel() {
        return nivel;
    }

    public void setNivel(int nivel) {
        this.nivel = nivel;
    }

    public int getExperiencia() {
        return experiencia;
    }

    public void setExperiencia(int experiencia) {
        this.experiencia = experiencia;
    }

    public float getFuerza() {
        return fuerza;
    }

    public void setFuerza(float fuerza) {
        this.fuerza = fuerza;
    }

    public float getInteligencia() {
        return inteligencia;
    }

    public void setInteligencia(float inteligencia) {
        this.inteligencia = inteligencia;
    }

    public float getAguante() {
        return aguante;
    }

    public void setAguante(float aguante) {
        this.aguante = aguante;
    }

    public float getAgilidad() {
        return agilidad;
    }

    public void setAgilidad(float agilidad) {
        this.agilidad = agilidad;
    }

    public float getSuerte() {
        return suerte;
    }

    public void setSuerte(float suerte) {
        this.suerte = suerte;
    }

    public float getDinero() {
        return dinero;
    }

    public void setDinero(float dinero) {
        this.dinero = dinero;
    }
}
```

And my BD:
[image]

Im using Spring, and when i enter to the path "/" i execute the insert, but i am geting:

```
SQL Error: 1064, SQLState: 42000
2015-03-26 13:09:20.050 ERROR 5764 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'character (agilidad, aguante, dinero, experiencia, fuerza, inteligencia, nivel, ' at line 1
```

This is how i call the insert:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String indexForm(Model model) {

    Character c = new Character();
    c.setNivel(1);
    c.setExperiencia(2);
    c.setFuerza(5);
    c.setInteligencia(10);
    c.setAguante(5);
    c.setAgilidad(3);
    c.setSuerte(2);
    c.setDinero(100);

    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    session.save(c);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();


    return "index";
}
```

I have search and i dont think i have a sql reserved keyword.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CHARACTER` is a [reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/reserved-words.html).  If you're going to name SQL objects with such words, then you must ensure that they are appropriately quoted.

Adapting [Pascal Thivent's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3463189) to [Creating field with reserved word name with JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2224503):

With Hibernate as JPA 1.0 provider, you can escape a reserved keyword by enclosing it within backticks:

```
@Table(name = "`character`")
```

This is the syntax inherited from Hiberate Core:

> #### [5.4. SQL quoted identifiers](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/manual/en-US/html/mapping.html#mapping-quotedidentifiers)
>
> You can force Hibernate to quote an
>   identifier in the generated SQL by
>   enclosing the table or column name in
>   backticks in the mapping document.
>   Hibernate will use the correct
>   quotation style for the SQL Dialect.
>   This is usually double quotes, but the
>   SQL Server uses brackets and MySQL
>   uses backticks.
>
> ```
> <class name="LineItem" table="`Line Item`">
>     <id name="id" column="`Item Id`"/><generator class="assigned"/></id>
>     <property name="itemNumber" column="`Item #`"/>
>     ...
> </class>
> ```

In JPA 2.0, the syntax is standardized and becomes:

```
@Table(name="\"character\"")
```

#### References

- Hibernate reference guide

  - [5.4. SQL quoted identifiers](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/manual/en-US/html/mapping.html#mapping-quotedidentifiers)
- JPA 2.0 specification

  - 2.13 Naming of Database Objects

#### Related questions

- [Hibernate, MySQL and table named “Repeat” - strange behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3217479/hibernate-mysql-and-table-named-repeat-strange-behaviour)
- [Automatic reserved word escaping for Hibernate tables and columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3364835/automatic-reserved-word-escaping-for-hibernate-tables-and-columns)

Answer (score 0):

Change your table name and coloumn names. Ex: Change 'Nombre' to 'nombre' . (Remove Capital letter in all columns).