# Unable to retrieve data from SQLite database because of table's name.(Hibernate)

Tags: database, hibernate, sqlite

I have a tabe in my database with name "Group". 
This is my model code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Group")
public class Group {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="group_id")
private int id;
@Column(name="name")
private String name;
@Column(name="color")
private String color;

public Group(){
    this(null,null);
}

public Group(String name, String color){
    this.name=name;
    this.color=color;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getColor() {
    return color;
}

public void setColor(String color) {
    this.color = color;
}

}
```

I'm trying to retrieve data from database using:

```
     Session session=mainApp.getSessionFactory().openSession();
     groupList=FXCollections.observableArrayList(session.createCriteria(Group.class).list());
     groupPicker.setItems(groupList);
     session.close();
```

But it gives me an error(`SQL error or missing database (near "Group": syntax error)`). I know that it is happening because hibernate generates query similar to this: `SELECT * FROM Group`. To work properly it should be: `SELECT * FROM "Group"`, but I do not know how to achieve this.

Comment: The solution for me never use these names as table name or pojo

Comment: Solution: Don't call the table Group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I tried several different ways, I finally came up with a solution, which works. I just changed my model's table name to:`@Table(name="\"Group\"")`.

Answer (score 0):

If You are using XML somehow You can be interested in element *delimited-identifiers* to force quoting of all entities. More can be found [Hibernate, MySQL and table named "Repeat" - strange behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3217479/hibernate-mysql-and-table-named-repeat-strange-behaviour)