# Simple tooltip - Title Attribute?

Tags: html, tooltip

When I want to have a message show when a user mouse overs an object, and lately I just use the *title* attribute on my html tags since it's simple and automatically doesn't go off screen.

**Question:** Is using the *title* attribute is a bad thing to rely on for a tool-tip?

Ignoring the fact you can't customize it, I'm curious about functionality over using a custom made tool-tip (such as how the standard user interacts with it). A [specific web-comic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/84589/1411473) I read, for example, uses the *title* attribute to add a witty comment / factoid when you hover over it. Yet not many people seem to know about it.

As such it seems a *title* might be good for a comment, or even saying author of a picture, but is it good for a true simply tool-tip?

Considering for a 'real' tool-tip you need usually 1-2 extra elements, css (and depending how you set it up, possibly some inline style for placement), and possibly even java-script, is the *title* attribute bad to use since (again) it cannot be customized, is often a small off-topic detail about the element, and only appears after a set amount of time.

**Note:** If it helps (food for thought), my current situation that brought this question on, is I like when a site has something like `[?]` for you to hover over to find more details without shoving them into the page, thus keeping it simple.
Also, I learned html from w3schools, and they never mention the *title* attribute, so not really sure what they are intended / should be used for. (and yes, mentioning w3schools part was a (bad) attempt at getting sympathy)

And I find this question kind of weird to ask considering SO uses them quite a bit, but feel free to assume I know nothing about it as... well... I really don't)

Comment: You had my sympathy already, just for 'learning html from W3Schools.'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The title attribute (@title), should not be used.

1. Every browser does their own thing with the @title, even though it looks the same.
2. For people who just use the keyboard, they cannot get the information in @title.
3. People accessing the site from a mobile device, cannot get the information.
4. Some, but not all assistive technology can get the information in the @title

   1. some  allows it to be read after enabling it. Which not many people (users) know about.
   2. other technology simply ignores the link text and reads the @title only.

Ex of 4.2:

```
<a href="#" title="Are you sure?">Delete your account</a>
```

This will read:

> Are you sure? Link

Further Reading: [PG: Title attribute](http://www.paciellogroup.com/blog/2012/01/html5-accessibility-chops-title-attribute-use-and-abuse/)

Comment: So it should really only be used as a side note that really won't be missed? And interesting read. Guess I'm back to the drawing board. Know any good article for making a real tool-tip by any chance? (Not as much how to code, but rather what you should think about / include.

Comment: Correct Kyomu, only a side note. I saw http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/NOTE-WCAG20-TECHS-20120103/G201 the other day. It is not about tooltips but new windows. The main information can be extracted.

Answer (score 0):

First of all,hats off to your question. Good thinking. I guess we people [I'm speaking about amateur coders like me] needn't develop a big site or rather lack that expertise. We simple need to keep getting our things done in an optimized manner. Therefore, similarily, I have also encountered almost every script using *title* for tooltips. Guess,it's the simple way to tackle it. Moreover, as long as the tooltip is attractive, isn't slow, and caters our need: its all good.

Answer (score 0):

The `title` attribute is simple, and simplistic. It is not reliable. No tooltip mechanism really is, but the tooltips generated by `title` attributes have rather poor usability: tiny font size, problems with line control, timed disappearance, no way (to normal users) to make it stay put so that you can actually read it even if you are a slow reader. Besides, there is normally no hint to the user about the availability of a tooltip.