# KNN choosing class label when k=4

Tags: machine-learning, classification, nearest-neighbor, knn

In k-NN classification, the output is a class membership. An object is classified by a majority vote of its neighbors, with the object being assigned to the class most common among its k nearest neighbors (k is a positive integer, typically small).

1. If k = 1, then the object is simply assigned to the class of that single nearest neighbor.
2. If k=3, and the class labels are Good =2 Bad=1,then the predicted class label will be Good,which contains the majority vote.
3. **If k=4, and the class labels are Good =2 Bad=2, What will be the class label?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are different approaches. For example Matlab uses 'random' or 'nearest' as documented [here](http://de.mathworks.com/help/bioinfo/ref/knnclassify.html).

> When classifying to more than two groups or when using an even value
>   for k, it might be necessary to break a tie in the number of nearest
>   neighbors. Options are 'random', which selects a random tiebreaker,
>   and 'nearest', which uses the nearest neighbor among the tied groups
>   to break the tie.

Comment: Yes, that is one way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is **not specific to k=4**.

Consider a data set with 3 classes. At k=2, two different classes may arise. At k=3, three different classes may arise, at k=4, it may be 0,2,2... any k beyond 1 bears the risk of a *tie*.

Choose one at random, or use weighting (i.e. give the 1NN more weight than the 2nd nearest neighbor etc.) to further reduce the risk of ties.

Comment: How can we choose that at random?

Comment: Pick a random one of those that are maximal.

Comment: @HasQUIT--Anony-Mousse the easiest way is to implement function like here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/84747/2047418