# Why my query result returns me false

Tags: java, sql

I'm new with java and sql query and for the user connexion, I connect to the DB and check if the login exists. Here is what I do :

```
requete = "SELECT Login,Password,DroitModifAnnuaire,DroitRecepteurDem,DroitResponsableDem,PiloteIso,Administrateur,DroitNews,DroitTenues,DroitEssai,Nom,Prenom  FROM Annuaire WHERE Login='"
            + (request.getParameter("login") + "'");
instruction = connexion.createStatement();
jeuResultats = instruction.executeQuery(requete);
try{            
    jeuResultats.next();
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
if (jeuResultats.next() == false) {
   loadJSP("/index.jsp", request, reponse);
}else {
    loadJSP("/views/menu.jsp", request, reponse);
}
```

The login that I enter is good but it redirect me to `index.jsp`and I have the error : `the result set has no current row`

I tried to search answer to this error but I didn't found. So why it returns me `false` ? While when I do `System.out.println(jeuResultats.getString(1));` the login is printed.

Comment: you call next twice. becaues of that you check in "if (jeuResultats.next() == false) " if there is a second row

Comment: @Simo Oh yes thank you, it works now

Comment: I want to login with `TT'; DROP TABLE Annuaire;--`

Comment: @TT. How can I prevent from SQL injection in java ?

Comment: @TT. [Little Bobby Tables](http://stackoverflow.com/a/84629/1682559) ;)

Comment: If you wonder why, read this [TN on SQL Injection](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`jeuResultats.next();` moves your result to the next row. You start with 0th row, i.e. when you call `.next()` it reads the first row, then when you call it again, it tries to read the 2nd row, which does not exist.

*Some additional hints, not directly related to the question:*

1. Java Docs are a good place to start [Java 8 ResultSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html), for e.x., perhaps  `ResultSet.first()` method may be more suited for your use.
2. Since you are working with resources, take a look at try-with-resources syntax. [Official tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) are a good starting point for that.
3. Also take a look at prepared statement vs Statement. Again, [official guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) is a good place to start

Answer (score 1):

Make the below changes in you code. Currently the next() method is shifting result list to fetch the data at 1st index, whereas the data is at the 0th Index:

```
boolean result = false;
try{            
    result = jeuResultats.next();
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
if (!result) {
   loadJSP("/index.jsp", request, reponse);
}else {
    loadJSP("/views/menu.jsp", request, reponse);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code by below code:

```
requete = "SELECT Login, Password, DroitModifAnnuaire, DroitRecepteurDem, DroitResponsableDem, PiloteIso, Administrateur, DroitNews, DroitTenues, DroitEssai, Nom, Prenom  FROM Annuaire WHERE Login = '"
            + (request.getParameter("login") + "'");
instruction = connexion.createStatement();
jeuResultats = instruction.executeQuery(requete);

try{            
   if (jeuResultats.next()) {
      loadJSP("/index.jsp", request, reponse);
   } else {
      loadJSP("/views/menu.jsp", request, reponse);
   }
} catch (SQLException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```