# Who gave SWI-Prolog a sense of humor?

Tags: swi-prolog

Who gave SWI-Prolog a sense of humor?

```
Welcome to SWI-Prolog (threaded, 64 bits, version 7.3.35)
SWI-Prolog comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY. This is free software.
Please run ?- license. for legal details.

For online help and background, visit http://www.swi-prolog.org
For built-in help, use ?- help(Topic). or ?- apropos(Word).


1 ?- Input.  
% ... 1,000,000 ............ 10,000,000 years later  
%   
%       >> 42 << (last release gives the question)
1 ?-
```

Comment: That's the first time you encounter that? :)

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Yes!, it was a typo.

Comment: For others who upvote and have a [sense of humor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/84556/1243762)

Comment: [There from the beginning of git history at any rate](https://github.com/SWI-Prolog/swipl-devel/commit/97f1b0bbcedbb7598775a40caacbe16f139f28d8#diff-4eca7adb4b14551e006bd8363605e17dR174)

Comment: @genpfault Put `Jan Wielemaker` as the answer and I will accept it, then you can claim some rep in the land of Prolog.

Comment: @GuyCoder: Eh, sure, what the heck :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jan Wielemaker at [The Beginning of Time! (Time!...Time...time...)](https://github.com/SWI-Prolog/swipl-devel/commit/97f1b0bbcedbb7598775a40caacbe16f139f28d8#diff-4eca7adb4b14551e006bd8363605e17dR174)

[Commit `97f1b0bbcedbb7598775a40caacbe16f139f28d8` on May 26, 1992](https://github.com/SWI-Prolog/swipl-devel/blob/97f1b0bbcedbb7598775a40caacbe16f139f28d8/boot/toplevel.pl#L172-L176):

```
$execute(Var, _) :-
    var(Var), !,
    $ttyformat('... 1,000,000 ............ 10,000,000 years later~n~n'),
    $ttyformat('~t~8|>> 42 << (last release gives the question)~n'),
fail.
```